# mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi my I need to connect mysql database using PHP, my code looks below,

```
<?php
/**
 * A class file to connect to database

*/

class DB_CONNECT {  
// constructor
    function __construct() {   
    }

// destructor
    function __destruct() {    
 // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

 /**
     * Function to connect with database  
 */
    function connect() {

 // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

 // Connecting to mysql database
    $con =  mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die("Data base connection failed....! " . mysqli_error($con)); 
  // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }
  /**
     * Function to close db connection    
 */
    function close() {      
 // closing db connection
      mysqli_close($con);     
    }
}
?>
```

But I am getting the warning

```
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in db_connect.php on line 54
```

Is there any mistake on above code?

Comment: It should be function close($con)!

Comment: Ha. Where do you think the variable $con even comes from in `function close()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `$con` a private variable outside of the function.

```
<?php

    /**
     * A class file to connect to database

    */


    class DB_CONNECT {

        private $con = null;

    // constructor
        function __construct() {

        }


    // destructor
        function __destruct() {

     // closing db connection
            $this->con = null;
        }


     /**
         * Function to connect with database

     */
        function connect() {

     // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';


     // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->con =  mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die("Data base connection failed....! " . mysqli_error($con)); 


      // returing connection cursor
            return $this->con;
        }



      /**
         * Function to close db connection

     */
        function close() {

     // closing db connection
          mysqli_close($this->con);

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Then you can access it throughout the class. Also in your constructor call the `connect` function to ensure that the first thing it does is connect.

**Edit 1**

From what I can see your naming convention is a bit off too. Your class name `DB_CONNECT` looks like a `const` because that's how you have specified them in your `db_config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there is a `$con` variable is not initialized inside the `close()` function, the best option is to use make the entire class like this.

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {  

public $con;

    function __construct() {  

      $this->connect(); 
    }


    function __destruct() {    

        $this->close();
    }


    function connect() {

 // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

 // Connecting to mysql database
    $con =  mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die("Data base connection failed....! " . mysqli_error($con)); 
  // returing connection cursor
    $this->con=$con;
        return $con;
    }

    function close() {      
        mysqli_close($this->con);     
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see I have created a class level variable `$con` and using `$this` pointer I have initialized the class level variable `$con` inside the `connect()` function, and in the `close()` function it is the same class level variable to get the correct parameter it to close the database connection.

Comment: That is incorrect, `$con =  mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die("Data base connection failed....! " . mysqli_error($con));` `$con` is not defined. You mean `$this->con`?

Comment: initially in the programme $con is not defined, as we  know already that inside the functions the scope variable is always local, hence you have to use a common class level variable which should be accessible everywhere, just like the $this->con, which we are accessing using the $this pointer and the $con is a public/ protected/ private class level variable declared inside the class.

Comment: That makes no sense, why would you recreate locally (to that function) `$con` when you already have it declared at a class level?